# Booting issue in Ubuntu dual boot after upgrading

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, grub-efi

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 from a year now and yesterday I decided to go for the GUI upgrade option to 18.04 that keeps appearing after every software update.
Everything went well in the upgradation and right at the end it asked what to do with the changes in the GRUB configuration file and I chose to install the current version and proceeded, then an error popped up saying "ttf-corefonts" missing or couldn't be downloaded, and aborted the upgradation process.
Right after the upgradation got aborted, the GUI became strange, the wireless connection menu at the top right disappeared and no command would work in terminal.
Then an option came system needs restart and after selecting the Ubuntu option from GRUB startup menu, the booting gets stuck in a lock screen partially looking like Ubuntu 18.04 lock screen from then on.

My computer has been dual booted with Windows 10. I am not fully versed with Linux Ubuntu and GRUB customizations and can't figure out what to so in this situation. My examinations are near and I badly need the files stored in Ubuntu. Please help me out!

Comment: If your hard drive failed tommorrow you would restore from your backups any data you may consider important. Best to use live installer and see where you are at. Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI, often f12 but varies by vendor?